# facebook invite friends javascript api sends request only on mobile

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I was trying to implement the facebook invite friends facility on our website.

I used the following code to achieve the same

```
function inviteFriends() {
    FB.ui({
        method : 'apprequests',
        message : 'Invite your friends',
    },send_wall_invitation);
}

function send_wall_invitation(response) {
    FB.ui({
        method : 'apprequests',
        message : 'Invite your friends',
        to : response.to
    });
}
```

This opens the invite popup where you can select the friends. On clicking done it does not give any errors. But the invite friends notification are only seen on Facebook android application. In web notification no invite requests come.

Please let me know if i am doing anything wrong??

Comment: You should probably read https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

Comment: Thanks for the link. It tells that we cannot use the dialogue if we do not have facebook canvas.

Comment: Correct. It also tells you the options you have instead

Answer (score 0):

Facebook post says

> If your app does not have a presence on Facebook Canvas: You may use
>   the Message Dialog on iOS and Android, or the Send Dialog on Web.
>   These products let a person send a message directly to their friends
>   containing a link to your app. This type of message is a great channel
>   for communicating with a smaller number of people in a direct way. The
>   Message Dialog and the Send Dialog both include a typeahead which lets
>   the person easily select a number of friends to receive the invite.

So i am using the following snippet

```
FB.ui({
        method: 'send',
        name: 'People Argue Just to Win',
        link: 'http://gobzer.com',
        });
```